# Calculating distance between 2 points with sql

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight

I have to calculate the distance between 2 points, X and Y being the coordinates of the first point while axisX and axisY are the coordinates of the second point. My only lead is this SQL statement, however this SQL does not return the result I'm looking for. So can anyone help me identify any mistake I may have made with this statement?

```
string x = "SELECT TownName,Address,SUBSTRING(X, 1, 2) AS Xaxis, SUBSTRING(Y, 1, 2) AS Yaxis,Type,Availability,Price,Size,Bedrooms,Bathrooms,Contact,Screenshot1,Screenshot2,Screenshot3,Screenshot4 FROM House"+
                                    "WHERE (SQRT(POWER(X - "+axisX+" , 2) + POWER(Y - "+axisY+", 2)) <= 2000)";
```

Comment: You have the Silverlight tag attached; perhaps you could just return the points to your Silverlight app and calculate the distance there? (If not, then please remove the tag.)

Comment: did you check nerddinner project?. they have an implementation in order to check distance between two coordinates. this is the url http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65101#953014

Comment: When you concatenate the two lines, there's no space between 'House' and 'WHERE'. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT <replace with your select>,

3963.0 * ACOS (
    sin(SUBSTRING(X, 1, 2)/57.2958) * sin(" + axisX + "/57.2958) + cos(SUBSTRING(X, 1, 2)/57.2958) * cos(" + axisX + "/57.2958) * cos(" + axisY + "/57.2958 - SUBSTRING(Y, 1, 2)/57.2958))
as distance
 FROM House
ORDER BY distance
```

I'm assuming axisX and axisY are your co-ordinates. This uses the distance calculation technique which may provide you a more accurate reading.

http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this but there's an error saying "Incorrect syntax near '3963.0'"

Comment: Interesting, what DB are you using?

Comment: wat do u mean? my database name is database1.mdf

Comment: now i have another error  saying that +axisX+ and +axisY+ does not have a column name

Comment: Encapsulate my entire code block into string x = "<insert here>"; and that'll fix the problem. However, I am unsure if MSSQL can handle doing calculations raw like that. :( I only use MySQL/PGSQL

Comment: it still says tat there is incorrect error near < and >,i would like to ask the axisX and axisY is a set of coordinates that is retrieve from another page...how do i ensure that the coord is being brought foward to the sql